# Google Directory API: Credentials for managing groups

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm attempting to create a group and add members.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups

Which leads to

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

Which says:

"2. Activate the Directory API in the Google Developers Console. (If the API isn't listed in the Developers Console, then skip this step.)"

Question one is: There's no Directory API in the Console, and when I click on "Credentials", there's a popup that says "Enable the APIs you plan to use"; what to do?

Question two: Creating/Listing a group seems like it should be doable using a server api instead of OAuth? I tried creating a group using the server key from a different project (just for testing) through the oauthplayground (because it seemed like the only place I could see what's going on), and ended up with a 404 "Domain not found." error. In the Console, under Credentials, there is "Domain Verification", but that talks about using Web Hooks, which doesn't seem to apply here...what am I missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Upon further investigation, I've learned a couple of things:

1) As far as I can tell, the relevant API for this is "Admin SDK", however;

2) This all requires Google Apps for Work -- it doesn't apply to the "public" Google Groups, so seems like I am basically out of luck for doing this via API.

Comment: Have you completed the setup steps listed in [Directory API: Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites)?